# NSFileManager not deleting a file that exists

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfilemanager

I am having some problem with using the NSFileManager functionalities.
This happens both on the Simulator and an iPhone device (iOS 5.1).

Basically, I have a bunch of files that are stored in a document that I created. Now I am trying to move a file (stored at path) to the same directory with another name, to check if the deletion works.

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:path]) {
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:path toPath:[path            stringByAppendingString:@".deleted"] error:&error];
if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error removing file at path: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

The output of this is both files at *path* and *path*.deleted.
I ultimately just want to remove the file using *removeItemAtPath* but that is not working. It returns a success but if I see it in the file directory I can still see it there even after an hour.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to delete a file you should use `removeItemAtPath:myPath error:NULL` like

```
NSError *error;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:path]) {
    BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error removing file at path: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this too but it is not working either. The problem is just that whether I use moveItemAtPath or deleteItemAtPath, the file at path does not get deleted.

Comment: I found the problem in my code. It was just that I had started an NSTimer somewhere that would keep saving the file every few seconds, so even after delete, the file got written again giving the impression that it is not getting deleted. I am accepting this answer as technically is is correct.

Comment: I'd recommend adding in fileExistsAtPath with your logic as well. I've noticed sometimes isDeletableFileAtPath still returns true for awhile after the file has been deleted/removed, but fileExistsAtPath is always correct.

Answer (score 3):

I just figure it out of something very important when you use NSFileManager. You have to be aware of App Sandboxing.

```
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
```

This line return the path document directory of your app sandboxed. When you create a file with FileManager in your document directory (for e.g) don't save the full file path but only the path from the current document directory.

You'll be able to recreate the full path of your created file.

Hope (after 5 years) help over developers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use this for search path and delete a video

```
(NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
    }
NSString *dataFilePath = [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.nosync"]
                              stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@.mp4",[dicForDelete valueForKey:keyVideoId],[dicForDelete valueForKey:keyVideoName]]];
NSError *error;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:dataFilePath]) {
        BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:dataFilePath error:&error];
        if (success) {
          NSLog@"file deleted ");
        }else
        {
        NSLog@"file not deleted ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.  I'm still baffled as to why the fix works, but it's worth mentioning in case others can explain it.

I discovered that `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&error]` would return false on the first attempt but with a nil error.  On the second attempt it would return true.

Here's what my code looked like:

```
// success == NO error = nil
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeUrl error:&error]; 

// success == YES error = nil
success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeUrl error:&error];
```

I discovered that if I created my own NSFileManager instance, it would work on the first try.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
[fm removeItemAtURL:storeUrl error:&error];
```

I'm running on the iOS9 simulator.  This smells like a bug.  I'm going to file a radar.